# Replacing levels of a factor variable based on several conditions in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a factor variable (Category) in long format dataframe of 4 levels (Stage 2, Stage 1, Elevated, Normal) that I would like to replace with one level per ID (New.Category).

Conditions:

If there are >=2 'stage 2' in consecutive rows, I would like the level to be Stage 2 only.

If not, but there are >=2 'stage 1' in consecutive rows, I would like the level to be stage 1 only.

If not, but there are >=2 'elevated' in consecutive rows I would like the level to be elevated only.

If not, but there are >=2 'normal' in consecutive rows I would like the level to be normal only.

If per ID, there aren't two of the same level consecutively - I would like the level to be the level that appears most frequently per ID.

If all levels appear just once - I would like the level to be the highest level available. (the order of the levels from highest to lowest - stage 2, stage 1, elevated, normal).

Here is an example of my data:

```
ID <- c(3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10)
Category <- c("elevated", "elevated", "stage 2", "stage 1", "normal", "normal",
              "stage 1", "stage 1", "stage 1", "stage 2", "stage 2", "elevated",
              "stage 1", "elevated", "stage 1", "elevated", "stage 2", "stage 1", 
              "elevated")
df1 <- data.frame(ID, Category)
```

This is what I would like it to look like:
[image: DF2]

I hope this makes sense, thank you for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

We may have to `group_by` ID, then use a complex `case_when` statement.
It is still important to understand how to handle ties in the call to `which_max`.
This output is different from the desired because I bellieve you may have a different proposal to handle ties for "the most frequent" in the last condition.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(New.Category = case_when(any(Category == lag(Category) & Category == "stage 2") ~ "stage 2",
                                    any(Category == lag(Category) & Category == "elevated") ~ "elevated",
                                    any(Category == lag(Category) & Category == "normal") ~ "normal",
                                    .default = names(which.max(table(Category))))) %>%
    ungroup()

# A tibble: 19 × 3
      ID Category New.Category
   <dbl> <chr>    <chr>       
 1     3 elevated elevated    
 2     3 elevated elevated    
 3     3 stage 2  elevated    
 4     6 stage 1  normal      
 5     6 normal   normal      
 6     6 normal   normal      
 7     7 stage 1  stage 1     
 8     7 stage 1  stage 1     
 9     7 stage 1  stage 1     
10     8 stage 2  stage 2     
11     8 stage 2  stage 2     
12     8 elevated stage 2     
13     9 stage 1  elevated    
14     9 elevated elevated    
15     9 stage 1  elevated    
16     9 elevated elevated    
17    10 stage 2  elevated    
18    10 stage 1  elevated    
19    10 elevated elevated
```